# load data from DB at startup using caffeine cache and i need to use cached data whenever i want in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, caching

Configuration class to config caffeine

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig
{
    @Bean(name = "cacheManager")
    @Primary
    public CacheManager caffeineCacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        CaffeineCache definitionCache = new CaffeineCache("Cache_Data",
                Caffeine.newBuilder().maximumSize(400).build());
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(definitionCache));
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

---

```
/*Service class to get the data*/   
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheManager="cacheManager")
public class LocalCacheServiceImpl {
    @Cacheable("Cache_Data")
    public String getdata(String value)
    {   
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly provide your suggestion. Thanks in advance

Comment: Kindly specify your problem and provide your efforts.

Comment: Please find my scenario below:
1) Load data into Spring Cache(@Cachable) from DB at the time of startup.
2) Whenever I need those data's get it from Cache. 
here the question is how can i load data into spring cache in spring boot?